# Excel FV formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to apply a percentage to get a specific value.

For example:

```
Product price: $1000
Selling fee: 10%
```

If I want to get $1000 (product value) after the site applies its commission, what formula should I use?

In this case the result would be $1111

$1111 - 10% = $ 999.9 (rounding)

But how do I get the value $1111 having only two values: product price and percentage?

I'm currently using FV in my formula, with a manually adjusted percentage and I want to know what would be the right way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `=1000/(1-.1)` you can replace the `1000` and `.1` with the cells in which the values are found.  This is more a math question than an excel question

Comment: I knew it, it was something more mathematical. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a math problem, not a formula：

Try this formula in Excel:

```
=A2/(1-B2)
```

[image]